# Modifying a JSON file with two nested object types

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have created two custom types in TypeScript.

```
type ResponseModel = {
    label: string;
    questions?: QuestionModel[];
    id?: string;
};

type QuestionModel = {
    label: string;
    responses?: ResponseModel[];
    id?: string;
};
```

From these two types, I build a `QuestionModel` JSON file. Here's an example

```
{
    "label": "your destination?",
    "responses": [
        {
            "label": "USA",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "label": "do you have a visa?",
                    "responses": [
                        {
                            "label": "yes"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "no"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Canada",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "label": "do you have a work licence?",
                    "responses": [
                        {
                            "label": "yes"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "no"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is just a small example, the file can be much longer than this one with a differnt content.

I want to build a loop that adds the id on each question and on each answer so that I get the following result.

```
{
    "label": "your destination?",
    "id": "yourdestination?",
    "responses": [
        {
            "label": "USA",
            "id": "yourdestination?_USA",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "label": "do you have a visa?",
                    "id": "yourdestination?_USA_doyouhaveavisa?",
                    "responses": [
                        {
                            "label": "yes",
                            "id": "yourdestination?_USA_doyouhaveavisa?_yes"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "no",
                            "id": "yourdestination?_USA_doyouhaveavisa?_no"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Canada",
            "id": "yourdestination?_Canada",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "label": "do you have a work licence?",
                    "id": "yourdestination?_Canada_doyouhaveaworklicence?",
                    "responses": [
                        {
                            "label": "yes",
                            "id": "yourdestination?_Canada_doyouhaveaworklicence?_yes"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "no",
                            "id": "yourdestination?_Canada_doyouhaveaworklicence?_no"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My problem is to build nested ids, so how do I read the objects in their nested order from start to end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a standard [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) procedure:

```
const identify = (data: QuestionModel | ResponseModel, path='') => {
  data.id = path + (path ? '_' : '') + data.label.replace(/\s+/g, '');

  if ('questions' in data) data.questions?.forEach((q) => identify(q, data.id));
  if ('responses' in data) data.responses?.forEach((r) => identify(r, data.id));

  return data;
};
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOYD2A7eECySAmEA2UAvFAN4BQUUeAhgEb4BcU8wATgJYoDmA3BVAEcArgmDtU8APxMAiiJbiUWXHgDaAXT6V22aczadeZAL58yoSFDmjFy-EVL8a9PExYduWqKwTI0CPThECUwcfA0vHT13Qz5TMjIAYwlgKB0IFDEAMxAHAApsamBqWXkxVDsCAB9YXxDKgBooMCKAC0IAcg6ASiIAPkdKQuKAOh0HFuBWqABqKDzJ6ckoDoB9DqgmLt654eoR53wRnzAaRIg8gHoAHXgZy64m7Z4zbSz5juEbCQ3OKD3ensRl8FBJJCMskhWABRaiJVp5PICXqEAbpTLsHJIppAnTdbqRd55Do+YL+eC-FD-IrUQE0451cngyEwuEIvKsFFo3AYrGsHH0vEEhKUHzAISsKl7OJmZJoJB4CAHJBcPLo7IgPLkSgAIkOeB1TB1ICQEv+NhQRUUkh1DX4OtJfnQ8ENUFU2soUD1dHwrp1AFUAMoAQVt-F1IPKaFd7vDnu9Lj92CQUBNQigrWoADdoNQoFn2PBqDa7Z7446Qi6mLGy2WE76jSAEDq45RjE0PbWvfq-SgkC2u8Z1HGh-x24N4z2jQBhaiWwphuuRxRVt2dyc+g1G5Op00Z7O5qAAdyhAGsqOxzihziXW16K+SY+u61OvU2XXfx8+N4mjX2B7Wo5lkBUCjsY+JmGQQA)</sup>

For each nested question and response, you call the `identify()` function with the ID of its parent, and the `identify()` function appends the current label to that ID.